# How to find the help of the .builtin function in python?

Tags: python

In python suppose to find the help of the specific function we use help(function-name) but how to find the same for the .built in function in python such as help(.builtin-function name) but in the command terminal it throws error stating the respective keyword is not found? Thanks in advance and sorry for the language(not comparatively lucid)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the really correct answer, but here is a link with all the built-in functions sorted in alphabetic order : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html
Enjoy !

Comment: For eg. .strip() method to which i want to see the documentation in my python terminal is there any way to do it in terminal itself?

Comment: `strip` is not a built-in function, it is a string method. Are you talking about the methods OR built-in functions?

Comment: by the way methods and inbuilt function are same implying of different class and common class. But by the question methods

Comment: @sridhattaaithal Not sure what you mean. You CAN'T use or access `methods` if you don't know the classes where they are defined. You can just start using built-in `functions` directly. That is the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is access the documentation of a method, e.g. `help(str.strip)`. You must provide the name of the method together with the class name (`str` in this case).

Comment: suppose if I don't know the class then?

Comment: @sridhattaaithal This makes no sense, you always know the class!

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc):

> The built-in function ***help()*** invokes the online help system in the
>   interactive interpreter, which uses ***pydoc*** to generate its
>   documentation as text on the console.

And

> For modules, classes, functions and methods, the displayed
>   documentation is derived from the ***docstring*** (i.e. the ***__doc__***
>   attribute) of the object, and recursively of its documentable members.

So, you can simply access ***__doc__*** attribute of the functions. For example,

```py
print(help.__doc__)
```

> Define the builtin 'help'.
>
> This is a wrapper around pydoc.help that provides a helpful message
>   when 'help' is typed at the Python interactive prompt.
>
> Calling help() at the Python prompt starts an interactive help
>   session. Calling help(thing) prints help for the python object
>   'thing'.

This works with any built-in functions or methods.

Comment: I did'nt get it for strip method please help

Comment: @sridhattaaithal `strip` is a string method, so you need to do `str.strip.__doc__`

Comment: so is there any way by which i can know that a strip method exist in the string class from the terminal itself likewise for other methods?